# using bayes' rule

Tags: probability, bayesian

Women carrying a certain gene are ten times more likely to develop breast cancer. Only 1 out of 100 women carries this gene. If a woman has breast cancer, what is the probability that she carries this gene?

Carrying the gene
$ P(C) = 1/100 = 0.01$

Probability of woman who has not the gene developing the cancer 
$P(D) = x$

Probability of woman who has the gene developing the cancer 
$P(D | C) = 10x$

I suppose that the question asks
$P(C | D) = ?$

Using bayesian formula we can find the answer

$$P(C|D)= \frac{P(D|C)*P(C)}{P(D)}$$

$$P(C|D)= \frac{10x*0.01}{x} = 0.1$$

Is this solution right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is that the probability of a woman *who does not have the gene developing the cancer* is actually $P(D|\overline{C})=x$, where $P(\overline{C})=1-P(C)=0.99$

Your application of Bayes' rule looks right in terms of the formula, however you need to proceed as follows:-
$$\begin{align}P(C|D)&= \frac{P(D|C)*P(C)}{P(D)}\\&= \frac{P(D|C)*P(C)}{P(D|\overline{C})P(\overline{C})+P(D|C)P(C)}\\&=\frac{10x\times0.01}{(x\times0.99)+(10x\times0.01)}=0.092\end{align}$$